# Normalizing 3D position data

Tags: dataset, data-transformation, normalization

I have a training set with 4 different 3D position vectors as some of the features. I have defined a new 3D coordinate system based on the first 3 of these position vectors to achieve translational and rotational invariance. Then transformed the original points to this new system. Since the last point also originally resides in the same coordinate system, I have transformed that one also. To explain the situation better:

Training data was before (Here assume first 3 vectors are used to describe the new coordinate system and $(x_s,y_s,z_s)$ is the last position vector which will also be converted):

$x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2, x_3, y_3, z_3, x_s, y_s, z_s\ldots$  (and other features)

Applying my coordinate system transformation it became

$x_{t1}, x_{t2}, z_{t2}, x_{t3}, x_{ts}, y_{ts}, z_{ts}\ldots$  (and other features)

Number of features decreased in the second case because in the new coordinate system some values are always zero ($y_{t1},y_{t2},z_{t1}$ etc) or equal to another value ($z_{t2} = -z_{t3}$)

The new features are not in similar value ranges, generally $x_{ts}, y_{ts}, z_{ts}$ are much larger than the others $x_{t1}, z_{t2}$ etc. So I want to introduce normalization, but at the same time I don't want to lose semantic relation between the points described in the same new coordinate system.

How should I do it? My initial thought is to look at min-max values of all $x_{t1}, x_{t2}, z_{t2}, x_{t3}, x_{ts}, y_{ts}, z_{ts}$ features and apply min-max normalization with same paramaters to each of them. So $z_{ts}$ for example will be much larger than $x_{t1}$ even after normalization. Does it make sense to do so?